# Get All Facebook Posts - Internal Server Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-fql

I want to get all the posts of a particular user .. i know that they're limited so I'm getting 100 posts each time...

```
$total2 = 0;
try {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 2000; $i = $i + 100) {
        $fql2 = "SELECT post_id, comments, message 
                FROM stream
                WHERE source_id = me() 
                LIMIT " . $i . "," . ($i + 100);
        $param2 = array(
            'method' => 'fql.query',
            'query' => $fql2,
            'callback' => ''
        );
        $fqlResult2 = $facebook->api($param2);
        $total2 = $total2 + count($fqlResult2);
    }
} catch (Exception $o) {
    d($o);
}
```

But upon running, the server is hanging giving a 500 (internal server error)..

when i make it 300 the loop iterator it will not hang...

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

your $parms2 array should look like this I believe:

```
        $param2 = array(
        'method' => 'fql.query',
        'access_token' => $access_token,
        'query' => $fql2,
        'callback' => ''
    );
```

I believe to get posts by user you need an access token so that you can get the posts that access_token has access to.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Batch Requests:

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

You can stack up to 50 calls in a Batch Request and it is much faster.